# Google App Engine - PHP Session data not retaining across subdomains/services

Tags: php, google-app-engine, session, session-cookies

I am using Google App Engine with multiple services within a single project. Each service has it's own subdomain (subdomain.domain.com). My goal is to have the session data be retained across the multiple subdomains. I have this working in my localhost development environment (Apache) and it works across the subdomains but not on GAE. Here is how I initialize the session (PHP7.2):

```
session_id('MySessionId');
session_name("MySessionName");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```

On each page, as the first piece of code, I use this code to continue a session.

```
session_name("MySessionName");
session_start();
```

When I look into the session cookie on Google Chrome each service appears set-up correctly. The session names, id/value and domains all match across the services. Yet each service only holds the data which it has created. The session data is not shared across the subdomains/services. It is my understanding the way GAE stores session data is in memcache and the data is available to all services under a project.
What am I overlooking which is particular to Google App Engine?

[what I have tried since the original post]
Today I wanted to see if there was something else in my programming causing the problem so I reduced it down to just starting a session.
Both subdomains/services have only the following in the index.php file.

```
session_name("MySessionName");
session_id('123456789');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.mydomain.com');
session_start();
$date = new \DateTime('now');
// in the first subdomain/service
$_SESSION['subdomain1'] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// in the second subdomain/service
$_SESSION['subdomain2'] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

print '<pre><hr>';
echo session_id() . '<br>';
print_r ($_SESSION);
print '<hr></pre>';
```

Even though the session cookies match in both subdomains, the session variables are different and only hold it's own session information.

Comment: I'd like to reproduce your project. Are you following documentation? Can you share the link with me?

Comment: Sadly, I can't share the link. It wouldn't do any good because you couldn't get pass the logins. I have gone over and over the documentation. It works as documented in localhost across 2 different localhost domains. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: You can try to reproduce the project with the above added information.

Answer (score 1):

It appears GCP/GAE may have different session storage for different instances (not well documented. I have no reference. It was based on different readings and trying different things over and over). I converted the sessions to work with the database based on what I found here http://phpsecurity.org/code/ch08-2. It was much easier than I thought. All is well again.